# Get closure information from Java functional interface

Tags: java, reflection, lambda, closures

I'd like to be able to access closure environment information at runtime from a Java functional interface. For example, I'm passing in a lambda, say, `(input) -> input + knownVariable` to a function `lambdaProcessor`.

Now, from within `lambdaProcessor`, I'd like to be able to access the environment associated with this lambda, and get the value of all the variables stored in this environment.

Is this possible? I don't mind having to create my own functional interface, or use reflection, etc.

I want the final output to be something like a map of `variable name -> value/address`. So I should be able to do this:

```
void lambdaProcessor(FunctionalInterfaceInstance l) {
    System.out.println(l.getEnvironment());
}
```

And it should print out

```
{"knownVariable": 10, ... }
```

Or even if it doesn't store variable names and just stores some kind of marker, I'd still like

```
{"reference1": 10, ... }
```

Comment: Why do you think you need this? You're not actually passing a _lambda_ at runtime. It's an instance like any other.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are are trying to do. When you define a lambda it remembers its context maybe if you provide an example of what you are tying to do we can help?

Comment: I need it because I want to record all the variables in the environment. And please don't tell me the architecture is wrong, I don't deny that, but sometimes there are way too many critical things tied up together that I'd rather not disturb it all.

Comment: @Joe.b I've updated the question

Comment: That's not how lambdas work. This is a classic [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @shmosel What is it that I really want? I'm receiving a lambda and I want to access the environment stored in the closure, which is the question.

Comment: You can't. Does that help?

Comment: It does, but I would also like to know why I can't, since this information must be stored _somewhere_

Comment: Why must it be stored in the lambda? Are you asking about *any* local variable, or specifically one passed into the lambda expression?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150229/discussion-between-asymptotically-and-shmosel).

Comment: I agree I don't think you can. You can have your lambda return this information for you. Not ideal but it could work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve captured variables from the generated lambda class using reflection. Note that this is very brittle, since the lambda class structure is unspecified and can change at any time (or may not even exist). Example:

```
static void printCaptures(Function<Integer, String> f) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(f.getClass());
    for (Field field : f.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println(field.getName() + ": " + field.get(f));
    }
}
```

[**Ideone Demo**](http://ideone.com/fuLPUV)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I agree that this isn't the best thing to have in the code base, but it'll be very helpful till I can figure out a better solution and implement it.